# Mongo driver not working after update PHP 5.3 to 5.4

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, centos, centos6

I've installed the PHP-MCRYPT package, so it automatically updated my PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 and now the Mongo driver is not loading.
Sometimes this error appears:

```
PHP startup mongo: Unable to initialize module
```

Should I have to update the mongo driver? How? I'm running a VPS CentOS 6 in Godaddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to reinstall the PHP [mongo driver from PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo). Try that and let me know how you get on.

Comment: I try to "pecl install mongo" but it says is already installed and the current version 1.3.4

Comment: after uninstalled mongo I've installed it again and now everything is working fine, thanks!